# Execute procedure in statement in NOT IN()

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE storedProcedureExample
    (@displayName NVARCHAR(256))
AS
    SELECT users.id --user.id is INT
    FROM users
    WHERE users.displayName = @displayName 
    -- there could be many ids from the same display name
```

How can I call it in a statement NOT IN?

Error example:

```
DECLARE @displayName NVARCHAR(256) = 'SomeRandomName'

SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (EXEC storedProcedureExample @displayName)
```

**Note**: I'm not interested in rewriting it more efficient. I just want to know how can I call the procedure within the NOT IN parameters. I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

on the closing parameters of the `EXEC`.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v17.1

Comment: why don't you use function instead of stored procedure and return some value

Comment: Because I wasn't sure you couldn't do it without a store procedure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly.  This is why you should use a *table valued function* rather than a stored procedure.

With a stored procedure, you would need to create a local table, `exec()` into the table, and then use the temporary table for the query.